# Recursive function to iterative

Tags: function, recursion, iteration

The following function is given:

```
    T(n, 0) = n, n >= 0,
    T(0, k) = k, k >= 0,
    T(n, k) = T(n - 1, k - 1) + T(n, k - 1) + 1, n > 0 and k > 0
```

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to convert it to an iterative version. I've already tried drawing a recursion tree to notice some dependencies, but I still can't figure it out.

Have you got some tips?

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: I know what this concept is all about, but haven't used it so far. I can't see where I can possibly apply its principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate `T(n, k)` you can use the following iterative approach:

- S(i) represents the vector with T(0,i) to T(n, i)
- Initialize your status vector S(0) with zeros
- For i=1 to k
- Calculate S(i) using S(i-1)
- Endfor
- Your result is the last element of S(i)

Note that you only need the most recent S(i), for memory efficiency you may store only it.

Comment: I had to initialize first row with i from 0 to k and then it'd worked. Thank you :)